Object type vs Object as const
I have this code:
const Type = {
  CALL_REMIND: 'CALL_REMIND',
  CALL_SCHEDULED: 'CALL_SCHEDULED',
} as const;
type Type = keyof typeof Type;

type TaskArgs = {
  [Type.CALL_REMIND]: { a: string };
  [Type.CALL_SCHEDULED]: { a: number; b: number };
};

type TaskMap = {
  [TType in Type]: (args: TaskArgs[TType]) => void;
};

const taskMap1 = {
  [Type.CALL_REMIND]: ({ a }: TaskArgs[typeof Type.CALL_REMIND]) => {},
  [Type.CALL_SCHEDULED]: ({ a, b }: TaskArgs[typeof Type.CALL_SCHEDULED]) => {},
};

const taskMap2: TaskMap = {
  [Type.CALL_REMIND]: ({ a }: TaskArgs[typeof Type.CALL_REMIND]) => {},
  [Type.CALL_SCHEDULED]: ({ a, b }: TaskArgs[typeof Type.CALL_SCHEDULED]) => {},
};

const send1 = <TType extends Type>(type: TType, payload: Parameters<typeof taskMap1[TType]>[0]) => {
  const res = taskMap1[type](payload);
  return res;
}

const send2 = <TType extends Type>(type: TType, payload: TaskArgs[TType]) => {
  const res = taskMap2[type](payload);
  return res;
}

Playground
I want to infer the args of a task mapper object (taskMap1 and taskMap2) on the args of a wrapper function (send1 and send2). I have previously asked a similar question (Overload functions does not infer the proper declaration signature in definition) but with overloads in mind. Taking into account the answer above, I came to a solution, send2, but I cannot understand why the send1 cannot infer the payload correctly and results to an error, even though the type seems to be the same of the mapper objects.

It looks like your Type should be an enum

@Bergi there is not any difference refactoring Type into an enum!

@AlexanderNenashev can you elaborate?

@pvarouktsis Yes, just saying that using enum is more idiomatic here; not meant as a solution

The only supported approach to this is described in ms/TS#47109 (same as in your previous question), where the types are explicitly using generic indices into mapped types over some base interface. TS cannot deduce such relationships; you have to tell it. Using a generic conditional type like Parameters<⋯TType⋯> doesn't count; TS doesn't know what Parameters means in the abstract, it can only evaluate for specific non-generic types. Otherwise it is confused and gives up. I'll find a duplicate for this question.

@jcalz Thank you very much, but I thought the behavior a bit weird because Typescript can infer an object type from its definition. Thanks a lot!
